# apache - additional mysql-installation without root

Tags: php, mysql, linux, apache

got some space at an intern SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 (x86_64) for the apache-webserver (apache 2.2.29, php 5.4.40) of our department.
Our php is built with Oracle, not MySQL. I wanna install MySQL additionally but due to our very strict guidelines I only have permissions to write in my "/usd/[user]"-directory, not "/var/lib" etc. so there is no possibility to run the command "rpm -i MySQL-server-5.6.25-1.sles11.x86_64.rpm" or sth like that.

```
user:/usd/as07100a/soft> rpm -i MySQL-server*
error: can't create transaction lock on /var/lib/rpm/__db.000
user:/usd/as07100a/soft> touch /var/lib/rpm/__db.000
touch: cannot touch `/var/lib/rpm/__db.000': Permission denied
```

Is there any known option I can install MySQL with my restricted permissions (e. g. kinda portable version)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this is possible:
[Install MySql without root access](http://www.bluecrownsoftware.com/article/271/Installing-MySQL-without-Root-Access-on-Linux)

Also see this post for additional configuration information: [Mysql - specify socket location](https://superuser.com/questions/311301/installing-mysql-without-root-access)

You will also likely need to change the port number in your configuration since OracleSQL is probably running on that port already. You can use netstat to see if any other program is listening on 3306.

```
netstat -ntl
```